# Conditional Where clause in Linq query for specific cases

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq

I have an entity framework query which is retrieving results from a database based on a specific criteria. However, there is an instance where I want to filter results based on a condition within the where clause. I think a case statement is how I would achieve this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

So, for results returned from the OutageList, for cases where the outage type is "Live", I only want it to be included in the results if the NumberOfPeopleAffected are more than 4. For example:

```
 outageList.Where(o => o.FaultType == "Live" && o.NumberOfPeopleAffected > 4)
```

The problem is, the above code isn't sufficient because I want to return other outages too, it's just that for the case of Live outages, I only want to return them if the Number of people affected is more than 4.

Does this make sense? Is it a case statement that I need? If so what's the best way to write this in LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have OR conditions inside your `Where()` clause:

```
outageList.Where(o => (o.FaultType == "Live" && o.NumberOfPeopleAffected > 4) || o.FaultType != "Live");
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It says "give me everything that does _not_ have faulttype = live, OR everything that _has_ faulttype = live AND NumberOfPeopleAffected > 4". brilliant

Comment: You can simplify that slightly - you don't need the `o.FaultType == "Live"` part of that since after the `o.FaultType != "Live"` the only things left are the live ones.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want in linq use below.

```
var faultList = new[] {"Live", "SomethingElse"};

outageList.Where(o => faultList.Contains(o.FaultType) && o.NumberOfPeopleAffected > (o.FaultType == "Live" ? 4 : 0));
```

To be honest I would be okay with using this statement but I realize its can be hard to read.

Comment: in retrospect i think its missing something, I might have been a bit too quick on the trigger...

Comment: ok fixed it.  @nicholas-reynolds answer works as well, my answer is "inclusive" meaning you need to specify the faultlist to return, his will return everything and only filter out FaultType == "Live" were the people affected is less than 4

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
 outageList.Where(o => (o.FaultType == "Live" && o.NumberOfPeopleAffected > 4) || o.FaultType != "Live")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because as you build up your query, the type is IQueryable, and because it will not actually hit the database (or whatever) and 'materialize' the results until you `.Select` or `.ToList()`, you might consider chaining your filters in `switch` / `if` clauses. This will effectively add a bunch or 'where' clauses to your query until you actually execute it.

eg:

```
if(case1)
outageList = outageList.Where(o => o.FaultType == "Live" && o.NumberOfPeopleAffected > 4)

if(case2)
outageList = outageList.Where(o => o.FaultType == "Unplanned" && o.NumberOfPeopleAffected > 0)

return outageList.Select(i => new myViewModel{
    prop1 = i.prop1,
    prop2 = i.prop2 // etc
})
```

Comment: The problem is that the OP wants case1 and case 2 at the same time. if you had case1 and case2 both true you'd get no results at all!